# What does it mean to pass one of the ByteArray types through GHC's FFI?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

In the Haskell2010 report, from [section 8.4.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1540008.4), there is a list of basic types that are supported in FFI import/export declarations:

> The following types constitute the set of basic foreign types:
>
> - `Char`, `Int`, `Double`, `Float`, and `Bool` as exported by the Haskell Prelude as well as
> - `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Word8`, `Word16`, `Word32`, `Word64`, `Ptr a`, `FunPtr a`, and `StablePtr a`, for any type `a`, as exported by Foreign
>     (Section 24).
>
> A Haskell system that implements the FFI needs to be able to pass
>   these types between the Haskell and the external context as function
>   arguments and results.

From the GHC manual section on extensions on FFI, [GHC adds to these types with some unboxed types](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#unboxed-types):

> The following unboxed types may be used as basic foreign types (see
>   FFI Addendum, Section 3.2): `Int#`, `Word#`, `Char#`, `Float#`,
>   `Double#`, `Addr#`, `StablePtr# a`, `MutableByteArray#`,
>   `ForeignObj#`, and `ByteArray#`.

It is pretty clear what happens for most of theses types at the level of the linker when i specify the `ccall` calling convention. For example, I'm pretty sure `Int`/`Int#` get passed on the stack as two 32-bit values. Similarly, `Ptr a`/`StablePtr a`/`StablePtr# a`/`Addr#` probably all get passed as pointers on the stack.

**What about `ByteArray#` and `MutableByteArray#`?**

All I can imagine is passing them as pointers, but that seems a bit nuts since, unless you make your `ByteArray#`/`MutableByteArray#` pinned, the GHC runtime might end up moving the array from under you. Also, you would be ignoring the size information also on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ThomasM.DuBuisson for digging up an [old email thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2014-June/114763.html):

> There is a way to pass an unpinned `ByteArray#` (or `MutableByteArray#`,
>   but the former seems right in your case) to a foreign call, using the
>   `UnliftedFFITypes` language extension. The `ByteArray#` is guaranteed to
>   not to be moved for the duration of the call. The code should treat
>   the `ByteArray#` argument as if it was a pointer to bytes. You will need
>   to do any address offset computations on the C side (i.e. pass any
>   offsets you need as extra argument to your C function).

So: these are passed as pointers and GHC's runtime promises not to move them from under you.